# .htaccess multi-domain redirect to respective domain's page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

We have completely updated our multi-domain website, hence many of our old urls are now defunct and we are planning to redirect them each to their respective domain.

Our current Server's Vhost configuration is such

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin user@domain.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/project/httpdocs"
    ServerName domain.uk
    ServerAlias www.domain.uk domain.de www.domain.de domain.fr www.domain.fr
    ErrorLog "/var/www/vhosts/project/logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "/var/www/vhosts/project/logs/access.log" combined
        <Directory "/var/www/vhosts/project/httpdocs">
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

So all domains points to same folder on server and hence share same .htaccess file as well.

We have following old urls that need to redirected to their respective domains, so could please someone shed some light on how can it be done.

- http://www.domain.uk/default1 -> http://www.domain.uk/def1
- http://www.domain.uk/default2 -> http://www.domain.uk/def2
- http://www.domain.uk/default3 -> http://www.domain.uk/def3
- http://www.domain.de/default1 -> http://www.domain.de/def1

I tried following but it doesn't work properly

`RewriteRule ^default1$ http://www.domain.uk/def1 [R=301,NC,NE,L]`

Required
 1. Redirect for http://www.domain.uk and http://www.domain.de, not http://www.domain.fr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this generic rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.fr$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(def)ault(1)/?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2 [R=301,NC,NE,L]
```